# Check an outpoint's scriptPubKey against known scripts

Tags: script

So I would like to check if `coin.out.scriptPubKey` is part of `GetScriptForDestination(mypubkey.GetID())`

A simple comparison isn't possible as the `scriptPubKey` (when I decode it) contains only the native SegWit address while the output `GetScriptForDestination()` will return all associated addresses.

Is there a nice and clean way to do this or do I need to work my way through?

Comment: GetScriptForDestination in the current Bitcoin Core source code returns a single script. There are no witnesses in scriptPubKey. I don't understand your question.

Comment: yes, my abilities to describe problems are pretty poor. if I decode the output of GetScriptForDestination, it contains all from legacy to native segwit. so I can't compare it directly to the scriptPubKey if I want to check if the Coin matches the provided key

Comment: I still don't get it. `GetScriptForDestination` only returns a single script, not all associated addresses (unless you're not talking about Bitcoin Core's current codebase).

Comment: Well, if you don’t get it, I may be up to something here. The codebase I am talking about is the current Core’s master branch. Actually the same thing I am doing now was working perfectly before, so I (maybe wrongfully) assumed that this comparison is now failing because on the old test and on live environment there was always at least one legacy prevout involved, now I am doing things on a plain SegWit environment, starting from coinbase. Definitely the scriptPubKey and the output from GetSctiptForDestination(mykey.GetID()) aren’t equal. The latter contains the first one though if I decode it

Comment: `GetScriptForDestination(mykey.GetID())` will give you the script corresponding to the P2PKH address for that key. If you want the P2WPKH address, use `GetScriptForDestination(WitnessV0KeyHash(mykey.GetID()))`. GetScriptForDestination always returns just a single script, though.